# Combine multiple rows into one based on column value (LIKE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have data as follows:

```
incidents   custname   startdate   enddate      desc   
6           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod1 mod1  
2           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod1 mod2  
2           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod1 mod3  
2           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod1 mod4  
6           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod2 mod1  
2           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod2 mod2  
2           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod2 mod3  
2           custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod2 mod4
```

Could be more than 4 but just for simplicity lets limit it.

Now what I want to do is SELECT only 1 row per product in which the number of incidents is summed up for all modules. So for example the output I want should look like this:

```
incidents   custname   startdate   enddate      desc   
12          custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod1 all mods  
12          custA      11/11/2013  11/11/2014   prod2 all mods
```

I have idea where to go with this or if I can even do something like this. The description field is a text field (nvarchar) so to get the product it would need to use LIKE to even find out what product it is correct?

So question is, is this possible? And if possible, give me a link to somewhere I can read about how to achieve this, I have no clue where to start...

Thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but you're definitely going to use a sum function on the incidents column, and probably a left function on the desc column. It won't be east to get the desc column exactly as you show in your expected, so I wonder how rigid that requirement is.

Comment: It's not that difficult to achieve the results you want with your example data. But it will be more difficult if the desc column can contain products which spaces or other more complex data. You need a way to be able to identify the product part of the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the description into two, so you can group by the product:

```
;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT incidents, custname, startdate, enddate
             , LEFT(descr, CHARINDEX(' ',descr)) AS prod
             , RIGHT(descr, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(descr))) AS Prod_Mod
        FROM Table1
      )
SELECT SUM(incidents) AS Incidents
      ,custname
      ,startdate
      ,enddate
      ,prod
      ,COUNT(distinct Prod_Mod) AS Mod_Count
FROM cte
GROUP BY custname
        ,startdate
        ,enddate
        ,prod
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/154df/4/0)

Note:  You may not want to group on all of those fields if the product spanned multiple dates, for instance, you may want the min/max date and remove it from the group by.

Update:  Sounds like you will need more complex logic to split the description field, consider using `CASE` statements:

```
CASE WHEN descr LIKE '%something%' THEN 'prod1'
     WHEN descr LIKE '%somethingelse%' THEN 'prod2'
     ....
     ELSE 'noprod'
END
```

Comment: Thanks! My description is not always the same so I can't split it into two, would this be possible to do using a LIKE? I was thinking '%prod1%' because it won't always be in the same location in the description

Comment: Most of the time its something like "prod1 mod first yr support plan" but there are changes where there could be more or less words, is there a way to split it so the prod part of the description is the prod and the whole second part is the second part? In other words instead of delimiting the second part by space just including all of it

Comment: Sadly you can't simply group by `LIKE`, see update for additional idea on how to split, you could also look into fuzzy grouping in SSIS.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up getting it working with LIKE, thanks for the help!